# How can I return a scala "object" as if it's a class instance?

Tags: scala

I have an abstract superclass with a variety of stateless implementations.  It seems like the thing to do is make the abstract superclass a `class`, and make each implementation an `object` because I only ever need one of each.

This is a toy example, but it shows the compile error I’m getting:

```
// Tramsformer.scala

class Transformer {
  def transform(value : String) : String
}

object Transformer {
  getTransformer(String : name) : Transformer = {
    name match {
      case "upper" => UpperTransformer
                      // I'm getting "Cannot Resolve Symbol" on UpperTransformer, 
                      // even though they're in the same package.
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("...")
    }
  }
}

// ---
// UpperTransformer.scala is in the same package
object UpperTransformer extends Transformer {
  override def transform(vlaue : String) = foo.toUpperCase()
}
```

I’m really shooting for some sort of dynamic dispatch on (dataProvider, desiredAction) here.

Then some class can call `Transformer.getTransformer("upper").transform("stack-overflow")` without making any unnecessary objects.

Any idea what I should be doing differently?  Should I stop worrying about premature optimization and learn to love the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't visibility, it's that you simply do not define an object named `UpperTransformer` anywhere - only a class. If you replace `class UpperTransformer` with `object UpperTransformer`, your code should work fine.

Comment: @EdBrannin Well, after fixing all your other typos (missing `abstract` for the Transformer class, `value` vs. `foo`, `String : name`), the code you posted works fine with `object` instead of `class`. So you should reconsider what your actual problem is (and make sure that your reproducible compilable code sample, actually compiles and reproduces your problem in the future).

Comment: Darn, sorry about that. I'll remake it by redacting the existing code later today.

Comment: OK, it turns out both classes started with `package main.scala` because of some _mostly_-fixed Maven setup.  After fixing that, the classes see each other and it works.  Thanks!